# Two django forms grouped in a parent class. Clean needs to access data from both forms for validation

Tags: django, forms, class, validation

I have

```
class JobAndEmployerPayScheduleForm():
"""
Group the JobForm and the EmployerPayScheduleForm
-- Valid all the forms and save all the objects together
"""

def __init__(self, job=None, post_data=None, files=None):
    self.job_form = JobForm(
        instance=job,
        data=post_data,
        files=None,
        prefix=None
    )

    self.employer_form = EmployerPayScheduleForm(
        instance=job.employer,
        data=post_data,
        files=files,
        prefix="employer"
    )
@property
def is_multipart(self):
    return True

def is_valid(self):
    return self.job_form.is_valid() and self.employer_form.is_valid()

def save(self):             
    job = self.job_form.save()
    job.employer = self.employer_form.save()

    return job
```

`pay_type` belongs to `job_form`, and `pay_schedule` belongs to `employer_form`. if `pay_type == "Pay Schedule"`, then `pay_schedule` must have a value. I can check both these values from `JobAndEmployerPayScheduleForm`'s save function, but raising a validation error from here causes the web app to crash with a server 500 error.

I can raise a validation error from `JobForm`'s clean function, but I don't know how to access the `pay_schedule` member variable belonging to the `EmployerPayScheduleForm` class.

Could someone tell me how to do this last, or some other way to successfully raise a validation error if the condition in the first paragraph is true.

For completeness, here are the two member models. The `JobForm` member function `clean_pay_type` is what I want to do, but it does not work.

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
#cat = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cat.objects.all())
pay_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PAY_TYPES, widget=forms.RadioSelect, required=True)
#pay_amount = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.TextInput, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = (
        'name',
        'summary',
        'instructions',
        'origin_ref',
        #'job_type',
        #'name',
        #'skills',
        'pay_type',
        'pay_amount',
        #'dstart',
        #'dend',
    )

def clean_pay_amount(self):
    d = self.cleaned_data
    pay_type = d.get('pay_type')
    pay_amount = d.get('pay_amount')
    if not pay_amount and not (pay_type == PAY_SCHEDULE or pay_type == AWARD):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Pay amount is required unless using pay schedule or award')
    if pay_amount and (pay_type == PAY_SCHEDULE or pay_type == AWARD):
        pay_amount = None

    return pay_amount

def clean_pay_type(self):
    d = self.cleaned_data
    ef_d = self.employer.cleaned_data

    pay_type = d.get('pay_type')
    pay_schedule = ef_d.get("pay_schedule")
    if pay_type == PAY_SCHEDULE and pay_schedule == None:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You need to upload a pay schedule if pay type is set to pay schedule")
    return pay_type
```

and

```
class EmployerPayScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Employer
    fields = ('pay_schedule', )
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to overload the initialisation to make the job form have a pointer to the employer form, make sure is_valid is called on the employer form pointed to by the job form, then I can access employer form data from job form's clean function

```
class JobAndEmployerPayScheduleForm():
"""
Group the JobForm and the EmployerPayScheduleForm
-- Valid all the forms and save all the objects together
"""

def __init__(self, job=None, post_data=None, files=None):
    self.employer_form = EmployerPayScheduleForm(
        instance=job.employer,
        data=post_data,
        files=files,
        prefix="employer"
    )

    self.job_form = JobForm(
        instance=job,
        data=post_data,
        files=None,
        prefix=None,
        employer_form = self.employer_form
    )

@property
def is_multipart(self):
    return True

def is_valid(self):
    return self.job_form.is_valid() and self.employer_form.is_valid()

def save(self):             
    job = self.job_form.save()
    job.employer = self.employer_form.save()

    return job



class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #cat = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cat.objects.all())
    pay_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PAY_TYPES, widget=forms.RadioSelect, required=True)
    #pay_amount = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.TextInput, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.employer_form = kwargs.pop('employer_form', None)
        super(JobForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = (
            'name',
            'summary',
            'instructions',
            'origin_ref',
            #'job_type',
            #'name',
            #'skills',
            'pay_type',
            'pay_amount',
            #'dstart',
            #'dend',
        )

    def clean_pay_amount(self):
        d = self.cleaned_data
        pay_type = d.get('pay_type')
        pay_amount = d.get('pay_amount')
        if not pay_amount and not (pay_type == PAY_SCHEDULE or pay_type == AWARD):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Pay amount is required unless using pay schedule or award')
        if pay_amount and (pay_type == PAY_SCHEDULE or pay_type == AWARD):
            pay_amount = None

        return pay_amount

    def clean_pay_type(self):
        d = self.cleaned_data
        # cleaned data is not available until is_valid is called
        if not self.employer_form.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError("invalid pay schedule")

        ef_d = self.employer_form.cleaned_data

        pay_type = d.get('pay_type')
        pay_schedule = ef_d.get("pay_schedule")
        if pay_type == PAY_SCHEDULE and pay_schedule == None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You need to upload a pay schedule if pay type is set to pay schedule")

        return pay_type
```